# jquery select inputs by multiple types

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form (with class `input`) with lots of `input` tags. I want to write `onchange`  event for the `input[type="text"]` and `input[type="number"]`

How to do it?

All i have now is:

```
$('.input input[type="number"],.input input[type="text"] ').change() ...
```

There has to be a shorter way of doing this

Comment: _"there has to be a shorter way of doing this"_ - why ...?

Comment: set all the inputs that you want an onchange event for to have the same class, and just use the class name

Comment: @CBroe is what i have mentioned, the *ONLY* way of doing this?

Comment: by the way, I don't see the point in giving all your `input` tags an `input` class...

Answer (score 3):

Use a common class for each input you want to use for the event.

```
<input class="changingInput" type="text">
<input class="changingInput" type="number">

$('.changingInput').change()
```

you can also limit it to only inputs with that class in case you also have the class on things that arent inputs

```
$('input.changingInput').change()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can

```
$('.input').find('input[type="number"], input[type="text"] ').change()
```

Another solution is to add a commons class for all the desired elements and access it via the class selector like `$('.my-inputs')`

Answer (score 0):

you can make it shorter by simple give them some attribute that can be used in every `input` like using the same class name(see Patrick answer) or give them attribute like

```
<input changeattribute="SomeValue" type="text">
<input changeattribute="SomeValue" type="number">
$('input[changeattribute="SomeValue"]').change()..
```